# Pandas SparseDataFrame lose column names when to_dense()ed

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I'm using pandas version 0.16.0 with python 2.7.

I have a SparseDataFrame with a multiindex on both the `columns` and `index` indices:

```
In [1]: df.index.names
Out[1]: FrozenList([u'Malicious', u'Environment', u'Agent Version', u'Datamodel Version', u'Operating System', u'User', u'Process', u'Unique ID', u'Valid', u'Count'])
```

And:

```
In [1]: df.columns.names
Out[1]: FrozenList([u'Feature', u'Parameter', u'Value'])
```

When I convert the DataFrame to a dense matrix the `index` multiindex names are kept intact:

```
In [1]: df.to_dense().index.names
Out[1]: FrozenList([u'Malicious', u'Environment', u'Agent Version', u'Datamodel Version', u'Operating System', u'User', u'Process', u'Unique ID', u'Valid', u'Count'])
```

However the `columns` multiindex names are lost and replaced with `None`

```
In [1]: df.to_dense().columns.names
Out[1]: FrozenList([None, None, None])
```

While keeping the multiindex structure.

I know i can simply reassign the previous names by doing

```
In [20]: dense = df.to_dense()
In [21]: dense.columns.names = df.columns.names
In [22]: dense.columns.names
Out[22]: FrozenList([u'Feature', u'Parameter', u'Value'])
```

But my question is why this happens in the first place, if that's the intended behavior, and if so - why?

Thanks!

Comment: This maybe a bug but what's the difference between `df.columns` and `df.columns.names`?

Comment: `df.columns` is the `MultiIndex` object, it's `names` attribute is a `FrozenList` describing the columns' names alone

Comment: Then this maybe a bug that it's not propagating the attributes when converting to a dense df, worth checking on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)

Comment: @EdChum: of course I checked already, couldn't find anything relevant.